# How do you change keyboard with swiftUI to reflect input type on segment selection?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Currently, I can dismiss and present the keyboard with a segmented picker corresponding to the alphanumeric or numeric keyboard input type on a SwiftUI view. I'm wondering how I can change the keyboard without it being dismissed and represented. So when the toggle is tapped the keyboard automatically adjusts. There is a minor inconvenience that I'm working around to make the UI more simple, as it requires an extra tap of the user.

```
public struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selectedInputType: Int = 0
@State private var keyboardType: KeyboardInputType = .name
@State private var selectedKeyboardType: KeyboardInputType = .name
@State private var inputTypes: KeyboardInputType.AllCases = KeyboardInputType.allCases

public var body: some View {
    Picker(selection: $selectedKeyboardType, label: Text("SomeInputHere")) {
        ForEach(0..<KeyboardInputType.allCases.count) { type in
            Text(self.inputTypes[type].description).tag(type)
        }
    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        
        .onReceive([self.selectedInputType].publisher.first(), perform: { (value) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.keyboardType = KeyboardInputType(rawValue: value)!
            }
            print(self.selectedInputType)
        })
}
```

}